# Equation notation

Tags: notation

A vector $x$ has $n$ elements and the $i$th element is refered by $x_i$.
I want to know the position of the element having maximum value provided $max(x)$>$A$ and different between 1st maximum and 2nd maximum greater than $B$. In case, any of these does not hold $true$ then return $0$.

$f = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
i & |x_i=max(x),x_i>A,max_1(x)-max_2(x)>B\\ 
0 & otherwise
\end{matrix}\right. $

I'm not sure about $max_1$ (first maximum) and $max_2$ (second maximum). I mean, is writing $max_1$ or $max_2$ correct in standard equation notation? If not, is there another way to write the same ?

(I'm need this to write in a journal paper so I'm looking for a standard form)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I well understand you have: $max_1(x)=x_j\ge x_k \forall x_k>B$ and $max_2(x)=x_h<x_k \forall x_k<max_1(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact I'm wondering if writing $max_1$ and $max_2$ are standard in equation notation ?

Comment: These are not standard notation as far as i know. you can specifiy what they means as in my comment, if my interpretation is correct...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll describe in text. Anyways, your interpretation is alsolutely okay.

Comment: You are wellcome. If my intrpretation is OK I can write an answer.

Comment: Sure. :)   why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know your notations $max(x)$, $max_1(x)$ and $max_2(x)$ are not standard but you can write a definition as:
$$
max_1(x)= x_j \ge x_k \forall x_k>B
$$
$$
max_2(x)= x_j > x_k \forall x_k>max_1(x)
$$
$$
max(x)= x_i \ge x_k \forall x_k>A
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get what you want here...

But you could have a function returning you the $max_1$ as you call it, and then, give it the vector $x$ to which you retire $max_1$, that would give you your $max_2$ of the vector $x$.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. But my question is little different. Is writing $max_1$ or $max_2$ common in equation notation ?